# Ansible "msg": "this module requires key=value arguments echo

Tags: command, ansible

I've just started learning ansible, and was following the docs. I am running commands, I haven't been into detail to  playbooks and stuff. 
I was able to ping successfully with

```
ansible --private-key ../key.pem  -vvvv all -m ping -u root
```

I have the IP in hosts file. So I was just running another command specified in the doc.

```
ansible --private-key ../key.pem  -vvvv all -m ping -u root  -a "/bin/echo batmaan"
```

which returns

> x.x.x.x | FAILED >> {
>       "failed": true, 
>       "msg": "this module requires key=value arguments (['/bin/echo', 'batmaan'])"
>   }

Any idea?

**Update**

I used **-m shell** before -a parameter and it worked. My ansible version is 1.4.4.  Why should be pass 'shell' when we tell the full path? Even the [docs](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/intro_getting_started.html#your-first-commands) doesn't say anything.  Is it a version specific issue? 
Please do help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here what ansible binary says:

```
  -a MODULE_ARGS, --args=MODULE_ARGS
                        module arguments

  -m MODULE_NAME, --module-name=MODULE_NAME
                        module name to execute (default=command)
```

So when you execute `ansible localhost -m ping`, ansible calls `ping` module to test connection with the host (localhost in this example).

When you try `ansible localhost -m ping -a "/bin/echo batmaan"`, you ask ansible to call `ping` module with `/bin/echo, batmaan` parameters, which is wrong.

There is a `shell` module to execute commands on remote hosts, so when you execute `ansible localhost -m shell -a "/bin/echo batmaan"`, you ask ansible to call `shell` module with your parameters, which executes `/bin/sh` with `"/bin/echo batmaan"`.

Notice that the default module to call is `command` (which is a bit different from `shell` module), which takes the first argument and executes it as a command with arguments that follows (but don't process them trough shell), so executing `ansible localhost -a "/bin/echo batmaan"` will execute `/bin/echo` with `batmaan` as parameter.

Comment: Great, got it. by using **-vvv** it logs in verbose so I should have checked this
`<x.x.x.x> REMOTE_MODULE ping echo baatman` 
my bad